# Pattern Recognition Questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is the https://math.stackexchange.com/ website appropiate for asking pattern recognition related questions?

If not, which one on stack-exchange?

Comment: It depends on the question itself. You could have a look  at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Funny enough, **this** question doesn't belong here. :-) Read the help center and make a judgement for yourself. No one can do that for you, since none of us know what your question is.

Comment: Older discussion, which is related: [What is the purpose of the (pattern-recognition) tag?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6588/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-pattern-recognition-tag)

Answer (score 2):

Both [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern-recognition) and [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern-recognition) have a tag for Pattern Recognition. You may have a look at both sites to decide which is more appropriate for your question.

Comment: In fact, look at the questions that have that tag --- you may find that the one you want to ask is already there!